# Different views depending on orientation on iOS

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

I know this question has been asked before, but how can I support a different view depending on my interface orientation in iOS 5?

An example by Apple shows a PortraitViewController and a LandscapeViewController. The PortraitViewController creates the LandscapeViewController and registers itself for rotation notifications. When it receives a rotation notification it either pushes or pops the LandscapeViewController depending on current interface orientation.

So far so good.

But how can I keep data both controllers have synchronized? (They display the same data obviously, since they are technically the same controller to the user, just with different views in landscape and portrait). Both have a "reload data button" which reloads their data. How can I tell the PortraitViewController to show the same data when the LandscapeViewController reloads it and vice versa?

Another problem is with memory warnings. When the interface is in landscape mode and I receive a memory warning my PortraitViewController gets unloaded. Now if I reload the data for my LandscapeViewController the PortraitViewController cannot do the same, because it is unloaded and has its Outlets still set to nil.

How do I adress all of these issues?

Comment: Why do you want to use two view controllers? Could you not use 1 view controller, with two views in it - one created for portrait, one specific for landscape. Then simply check device orientation on load and show the relevant view. Then do the same in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation ` to toggle which view is visible?

Comment: Then I'd have to have all views which are shared between the two views connected twice.

Comment: Do you mean the connections to other view controllers presented from the portrait/landscape view via a segue? If so you can connect them once to the view controller and trigger them by calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"name" sender:self];`

Comment: I mean Labels, etc. which appear in both landscape and portrait. But I guess that's just a minor annoyance.

Comment: I am just thinking what is best for performance and memory issues. If the view is relatively simple (but not necessarily) you could always consider one view, and adjust the frame of each labels, images etc depending on orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is using one ViewController with 2 views which shows a different view depending on interface orientation. The downside of this is that I have to connect all outlets twice and manipulate them twice.

But this way I can easily share my data and avoid one view being unloaded while the other isn't.

Answer (score 1):

you actually first have to make new xib...

go to file - new - file
select user interface
select view
and so on to make new XIB

now select new view
go to identity inspector in right panel
add class name to connect the xib to old .h and .m files

important step...

connect new xib view with file's owner

now new xib is connected with the oldviewcontroller .h and .m

last step

in appdelegate use if statement to change the nibname based on IOS

for this you can use this..
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]

in if statement you have to change initwithname with new view..

self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil] autorelease

Answer (score 0):

You should have a new class which will store your data. Both viewController will have a reference to this dataController (or whatever name you want).
You can also add a bit of logic on viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear of your viewControllers.
Finally, for the memory warning issue, you can check on the viewWillAppear is the view is loaded and act accordingly.